# How to tell which class is which with SHAP values in a summary plot?

Tags: python, shap

I ran a random forest classifier to predict pollen color based on various environmental variables. The possible predictions are purple or yellow. I want to run a summary plot in shapely to get an understanding on the importance of those variables. I run the following code:

```
import shap
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rfc)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
```

This correctly gives me the following graph:

[image]

Cool. This gives me a bunch of valuable information. But I don't understand what class 0 and class 1 are. Which is supposed to correspond to purple and which is supposed to correspond to yellow? I know its an unremarkable question for only 2 possibilities, but I plan on doing a classification with 3 classes and I need to know how the classes are assigned.

Comment: As a first guess, it may be determined by your `rfc` object.  Internally `sklearn` encodes the target variable, and that information is available in e.g. `rfc.classes_`.  I'm not sure if `shap` does anything to find those class labels, or just leaves that to the `sklearn` object...

Comment: @BenReiniger, it has to do something, because the 'rfc.classes_' are coded as 1 and 2, not 0 and 1

Comment: Really?  Then did you do some additional preprocessing?  I would've expected `rfc.classes_` to contain "yellow" and "purple"...?

Comment: You might find this post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71753428/how-to-get-shap-values-for-each-class-on-a-multiclass-classification-problem-in